# Error connecting to SQL Server (PHP - Wordpress)

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, woocommerce, sqlsrv

I'm trying to remotely connect to SQL Server through PHP in Wordpress.

This is my code

```
    $serverName = "IP"; 
    $username = "username";   
    $password = "password";  
    $database = "database"; 
    
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=> $database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

The error is this

```
Connection could not be established.Array
(
    [
    0
] => Array
        (
            [
    0
] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE
] => IMSSP
            [
    1
] => -49
            [code
] => -49
            [
    2
] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message
] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
        )

)
```

I think the error is from Wordpress and not from the remote server. In the PHP settings in Wordpress, the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv options are already active.

[image: Configuration sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv]

Comment: Wordpress doesn't natively support SQL Server, so have you installed some kind of alternative version, or coded your own changes to the build?

Comment: I configured it so that wordpress php has sqlsrv active. Please see the photo I added to the question.

Comment: Just adding the SQL Server libraries doesn't make Wordpress compatible with SQL Server.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow rita! i think this was asked off site before, on [wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/installation-with-mssql-db/). fyi, databases that supports [tag:sql] does share some construct and functionalities, but they often times behave differently and have additional features. which is why an app specifically written for [tag:mysql] might not work on [tag:sql-server].

Comment: I think most of you think I want to use SQL Server as my Wordpress database. I just want to make a connection to a remote SQL Server database for a WooCommerce integration.

Comment: It matters whether the machine running your php is a Windows machine or not. If it's not, you need to sort out the [ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) situation. Which is a notorious pain in the neck, and may not be possible on a budget hosting service. **Pro tip** read your error messages very carefully.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks for the reply, it was very helpful to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I finally managed to resolve this issue.

To better explain the environment:
I managed to make a connection through a Wordpress php file with a remote SQL Server database.
For this I used:

- WordPress store on a VPS
- Local machine (windows) on my network with SQL Server

First, I had the Wordpress store on a CloudLinux server, which didn't allow me root access over ssh.
I switched the wordpress store to a VPS.

In this VPS I had to install [all the PHP extensions that I had previously on the other server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfjIM.png), along with the [odbc drivers for sql server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#redhat17)

On the local machine I activated the remote environment, in which the access port was 3389.

Then I had to configure the router so that the firewall does not block communication. For that I made a forward on the router where I gave access to the VPS IP to the machine with SQL Server, which in my case is a local machine, for that I had to indicate the port (3389).

**Attention:** for the rules defined in the router to be active, it was necessary to restart!

To make the connection I used the following code:

```
    $serverName = "tcp:IP\DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS,1433"; 
    $username = "username";   
    $password = "password";  
    $database = "database"; 
    
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=> $database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password, "TrustServerCertificate"=>"Yes");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

The IP used was the public IP of the local machine.

If anyone has any questions let me know, I can try to help.